# How are Opcodes & Operands Defined in a CPU?

Tags: cpu, hardware, machine-code

Extensive searching has sent me in a loop over the course of 3 days, so I'm depending on you guys to help me catch a break.

Why exactly does one 8-bit sequence of high's and low's perform *this* action, and 8-bit sequence performs *that* action.

My intuition tells me that the CPU's circuitry **hard-wired** one binary sequence to do one thing, and another to do another thing. That would mean different Processor's with potentially different chip circuitry wouldn't define one particular binary sequence as the same action as another?

Is this why we have assembly? I need someone to confirm and/or correct my hypothesis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opcodes are not always 8 bits but yes, it is hardcoded/wired in the logic to isolate the opcode and then send you down a course of action based on that.  Think about how you would do it in an instruction set simulator, why would logic be any different?  Logic is simpler than software languages, there is no magic there. ONE, ZERO, AND, OR, NOT thats as complicated as it gets.

Along the same lines if I was given an instruction set document and you were given an instruction set document and told to create a processor or write an instruction set simulator.  Would we produce the exact same code?  Even if the variable names were different?  No.  Ideally we would have programs that are functionally the same, they both parse the instruction and execute it.  Logic is no different you give the spec to two engineers you might get two different processors that functionally are the same, one might perform better, etc.  Look at the long running processor families, x86 in particular, they re-invent that every couple-three years being instruction set compatible for the legacy instructions while sometimes adding new instructions.  Same for ARM and others.

And there are different instruction sets ARM is different from x86 is different from MIPS, the opcodes and/or bits you examine in the instruction vary, for none of these can you simply look at 8 bits, each you have some bits then if that is not enough to uniquely identify the instruction/operation then you need to examine some more bits, where those bits are what the rules are are very specific to each architecture.  Otherwise what would be the point of having different names for them if they were the same.

And this information was out there you just didnt look in the right places, there are countless open online courses on the topic, books that google should hit some pages on, as well as open source processor cores you can look at and countless instruction set simulators with source code.